# What is the use of binary output on stdout?

Tags: command-line, stdout

Some programs print their binary output directly on `stdout`. Here are some examples:

```
tar -c file.png
dd  if=file.png
```

Well, I see that the output can be redirected to a file. But these programs already accept output filenames as arguments. So, following commands will give the same results:

```
tar -c file.png  > file.tar
tar -c file.png -f file.tar

dd if=file.png  > copy.png
dd if=file.png of=copy.png
```

For what other purpose can binary output from `stdout` be used?

Comment: From a program's point of view, stdout is just a file descriptor which you can write() to. What is the use of *not* allowing binary output to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For building [pipelines](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29), obviously. The biggest advantage is that you can avoid having to create temporary files:

<sub>(For this example, assume an old version of `tar` which does not have `-J` or `-I` compression options.)</sub>

```
tar -c foo/*.png | xz -9 | uuencode "foo.tar.xz" | mail -s "Sending foo" musa
```

- Now imagine if you had to use `-f` and stuff... <sub>you'd have VMS.</sub>

  ```
  tar -cf foo.tar foo/*.png
  xz -9 -o foo.tar.xz foo.tar
  uuencode -o foo.uue foo.tar.xz 
  mail -a foo.uue -s "Sending foo" musa
  rm foo.tar foo.tar.xz foo.uue
  ```

You can do pipelines over the network:

```
ssh storageserver "cd ~/foo && tar -c bar" | pv | tar -x

curl https://example.com/secret.gpg | ssh mylaptop "gpg --decrypt" > secret.zip
```

More examples:

```
curl http://i.imgur.com/L1aOt.jpg | display
```

And sometimes you don't even *need* to pipe it anywhere, even if the output is "binary". Try this on a Xterm:

```
curl http://www.dim13.org/tek/teapot.tek         # Utah teapot
```

Answer (score -2):

Purposes may vary as per user. A developer can use that info for logging, or progress track or even error handling.

Comment: How do you log binary data, track progress or handle errors? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @slhck: [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml)

Comment: @grawity I know `pv`, but it would be nice for Mr. K to add a little more info.